# Как поправить меню категорий?

Tags: php

Уважаемые знатоки, внимание вопрос : Как убрать из submenu все эти дивы и i, и заменить на ссылки?

Есть класс:

```php
<?php

namespace app\widgets\menu;

use ishop\App;
use ishop\Cache;

class Menu{

    protected $data;
    protected $tree;
    protected $menuHtml;
    protected $tpl;
    protected $container = 'li';
    protected $class = 'menu';
    protected $table = 'category';
    protected $cache = 3600;
    protected $cacheKey = 'ishop_menu';
    protected $attrs = [];
    protected $prepend = '';

    public function __construct($options = []){
        $this->tpl = __DIR__ . '/menu_tpl/menu.php';
        $this->getOptions($options);
        $this->run();
    }

    protected function getOptions($options){
        foreach($options as $k => $v){
            if(property_exists($this, $k)){
                $this->$k = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    protected function run(){
        $cache = Cache::instance();
        $this->menuHtml = $cache->get($this->cacheKey);
        if(!$this->menuHtml){
            $this->data = App::$app->getProperty('cats');
            if(!$this->data){
                $this->data = $cats = \R::getAssoc("SELECT * FROM {$this->table}");
            }
            $this->tree = $this->getTree();
            $this->menuHtml = $this->getMenuHtml($this->tree);
            if($this->cache){
                $cache->set($this->cacheKey, $this->menuHtml, $this->cache);
            }
        }
        $this->output();
    }

    protected function output(){
        $attrs = '';
        if(!empty($this->attrs)){
            foreach($this->attrs as $k => $v){
                $attrs .= " $k='$v' ";
            }
        }
        echo "<{$this->container} class='{$this->class}' $attrs>";
            echo $this->prepend;
            echo $this->menuHtml;
        echo "</{$this->container}>";
    }

    protected function getTree(){
        $tree = [];
        $data = $this->data;
        foreach ($data as $id=>&$node) {
            if (!$node['parent_id']){
                $tree[$id] = &$node;
            }else{
                $data[$node['parent_id']]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
            }
        }
        return $tree;
    }

    protected function getMenuHtml($tree, $tab = ''){
        $str = '';
        foreach($tree as $id => $category){
            $str .= $this->catToTemplate($category, $tab, $id);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    protected function catToTemplate($category, $tab, $id){
        ob_start();
        require $this->tpl;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```

menu.php :

```php
<?php $parent = isset($category['childs']); ?>
 <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i><?=$category['title'];?><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<?php if(isset($category['childs'])): ?>             
 <ul class="submenu">         

<?= $this->getMenuHtml($category['childs']);?>

</ul>
<?php endif; ?>            
</li>
```

Как должна выглядеть структура меню:

```php
        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Категории<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Авто</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Животные</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Наборы<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Одежда</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

И что сейчас попадает в кэш:

```php
      <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Категории<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

          <ul class="submenu">

        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Авто<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

        </li>


        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Животные<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

        </li>

          </ul>

        </li>


        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Наборы<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

          <ul class="submenu">

        <li>
            <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Одежда<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>

        </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может как-то так?

menu.php :

```
<?php $parent = isset($category['childs']); ?>
<li>
    <?php if(empty($category['parent_id'])): ?>
        <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-database"></i><?=$category['title'];?><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <?php else; ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?=$category['title'];?></a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(isset($category['childs'])): ?>
        <ul class="submenu">         

        <?= $this->getMenuHtml($category['childs']);?>

        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Дааа, спасибо вам огромное, это то, что мне нужно